# django update function based view of multiple models

Tags: python, django

I have a parent model and two children models and I made a view to add multiple children to one parent
but I'm getting confused about making an update view for the parent with all children

this is the form to create multiple children
views.py

```
def create_day_view(request,pk):
    mydate = get_object_or_404(MyDate,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        length = request.POST.get('length')
        sof_zman_1 = request.POST.get('sof_zman_1')
        sof_zman_2 = request.POST.get('sof_zman_2')
        sof_zman_tefila = request.POST.get('sof_zman_tefila')
        ad_image = request.POST.get('ad_image')

        day_details = MyDateDetails.objects.create(
            date = mydate,
            sof_zman_1 = sof_zman_1,
            sof_zman_2 = sof_zman_2,
            sof_zman_tefila = sof_zman_tefila,
            ad_image = ad_image,
        )
        
        for file_num in range(0, int(length)):
            Image.objects.create(
                date = mydate,
                image = request.FILES.get(f'images{file_num}')
            )

    context = {'mydate': mydate}
    return render(request, 'luach/create_day.html',context=context)
```

I'm sharing the template so you will understand how the form works
create_day.html

```
{% extends 'luach/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class='container'>
    <div class="jumbotron myjumbotron">
        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-center " style="border-radius: 10px;">
            <h1 class='title-date text'>{{mydate.hebrew_date}}</h1>
            <h4 class='english-date'>{{mydate.english_date}}</h4>
        </div>
        <label>sof zman 1</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="time" id="sof_zman_1" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
        <label>sof zman 2</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="time" id="sof_zman_2" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
        <label>sof zman tefila</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="time" id="sof_zman_tefila" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!--<label>ad image</label>
        <input type="file" id="ad_image">-->
        <br>
        <label>Images</label>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="file" multiple>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var files = []
        FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateSize);
        FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginFileValidateType);
        FilePond.setOptions({
            allowMultiple:true,
            maxFiles:10,
            maxFileSize: '10MB'
        })
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
        const pond = FilePond.create( inputElement, {
            acceptedFileTypes:['image/png', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg'],
            onaddfile: (err, fileItem) => {
                if (!err) {
                files.push(fileItem.file)
                }
                console.log(files)
            },
            onremovefile: (err, fileItem) => {
                const index = files.indexOf(fileItem.file)
                if (index > -1) {
                    files.splice(index, 1)
                }
                console.log(files)
            }
        } );

        var formData = new FormData();
        $(document).on('click', '#saveBtn', function(e) {
            formData.append('length', files.length)
            formData.append('sof_zman_1', $('#sof_zman_1').val())
            formData.append('sof_zman_2', $('#sof_zman_2').val())
            formData.append('sof_zman_tefila', $('#sof_zman_tefila').val())
            formData.append('ad_image', $('#ad_image').val())
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append('images' + i, files[i])
            }
            formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}')

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "day_new" pk=mydate.pk %}',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: function (){
                    //alert('The post has been created!')
                    window.location.href = "{% url 'date_detail' pk=mydate.pk %}";
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    console.log(xhr.status + ":" + xhr.responseText)
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
{% endblock  %}
```